# Cordova not finding avd

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, sdk, android-emulator

After following the instructions for setting up Cordova for Android development on the [Cordova documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html), I encountered this error:

```
Error: No emulator images (avds) found.
1. Download desired System Image by running: /Users/Jacob/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android sdk
2. Create an AVD by running: /Users/Jacob/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android avd
HINT: For a faster emulator, use an Intel System Image and install the HAXM device driver
```

Every other post I found only said to **add** an emulator, but I have already done that. In Android Studio, I have in fact made three!

It is also worth mentioning that Cordova **used** to be able to run the emulator, but in attempting to fix another problem, I ran into this one. **I did run into a problem with permissions, and now have to use `sudo` every time I run a Cordova command. Could that have anything to do with it?**

Here is my .bash_profile:

```
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/Jacob/Library/Android/sdk
PATH=${PATH}:/Users/Jacob/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:/Users/Jacob/Library/Android/sdk/tools
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home
```

I have been trying to use the Android API level 23 with Android 5.1.1 in Cordova.

After trying everything I could think of (as a Terminal newbie :p), I'm out of ideas. I have tried reinstalling the Android SDK with all the packages, node.js (perhaps not entirely cleaning log files/caches), and Cordova, but to no avail. Is there anything in particular I could just reinstall so that the problem would probably disappear without much fixing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar issue and have found one way around it.

Try opening your Android SDK manager > tools > Manage SDKs...

Select an AVD and click start. Once booted, try the comment `cordova run android` (with sudo if necessary) and it should work on the running emulator.

When debugging, I find it much better to plug in an actual device - the experience is much smoother and you get better feel for what the app actually looks and runs like on a real device, whereas on the SDK emulator Cordova often runs quite slowly.

You can find instructions for that [here](http://geeklearning.io/apache-cordova-and-remote-debugging-on-android/).

Comment: This worked great! But I think I will take your advice on testing actual devices versus the emulator. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Got it! After some messing around, I found two files:

```
/Users/Jacob/.config/configstore/update-notifier-cordova.json
/Users/Jacob/.config/configstore/update-notifier-phonegap.json
```

By pressing `CMD+I`, I could see that their permissions did not include the admin (my name). So after adding my name to their permissions, I don't have to use `sudo` nearly as much and the emulator worked perfectly! :)

Answer (score 0):

what you mean by 'I  have been trying to use the Android API level 23 with Android 5.1.1' ?

Api 23 = marshmallow = android 6

You must have updated cordova i guess.i use ionic i got this after updating cordova and ionic.

either dcrease the target sdk in manifest or download latest system-image/sdk for api 23. since cordova/equivalent framework will always try building with latest api level.

for now you can try changing target sdk in manifest.config.xml

Comment: Cordova only supports Android 5.X.X, but the latest version of Cordova supports deploying apps for API level 23 (Marshmallow). It isn't an updating problem, but the help is much appreciated!