# The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object - Cordova + Angular

Tags: android, angular, cordova

I am creating a mobile application from a previously created angular app. I have used [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JiIGcmHtDDE) tutorial which explains how to create a native application from angular using cordova. I had carried out the following steps:

- Installed cordova
- Added environment variables
- Added Cordova to application
- Created a cordova app using `cordova create mobile`, which created the cordova project in `<myprojectpath>/mobile`
- Created a soft link `www` which redirects to dist folder of application
- Added android as platform (using `sudo` permissions, unable to do otherwise)
- Created build
- checked requirements using `cordova requirements` to see if anything is missing
- ran `cordova run android` in terminal (using `sudo` permissions, unable to do otherwise)

It gave me the following error:

> The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object

Gave the following information just before the error

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions  
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)  
ANDROID_HOME=/home/<usr>/Android/Sdk (DEPRECATED)  
No target specified and no devices found, deploying to emulator  
No emulator specified, defaulting to Pixel_API_28
```

Adding `--verbose` gave me the following:

```
The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type object
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:112:11)
    at Object.dirname (path.js:1129:5)
    at /var/www/html/employee_portal/mobile/platforms/android/cordova/lib/emulator.js:294:37
    at _fulfilled (/var/www/html/employee_portal/mobile/node_modules/q/q.js:854:54)
    at /var/www/html/employee_portal/mobile/node_modules/q/q.js:883:30
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/var/www/html/employee_portal/mobile/node_modules/q/q.js:816:13)
    at /var/www/html/employee_portal/mobile/node_modules/q/q.js:624:44
    at runSingle (/var/www/html/employee_portal/mobile/node_modules/q/q.js:137:13)
    at flush (/var/www/html/employee_portal/mobile/node_modules/q/q.js:125:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
```

I've checked a few questions on stackoverflow which point to similar problems associated with  ionic such as [undefined path error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59712879/cordova-ionic-the-path-argument-must-be-of-type-string-received-type-undefi) and [path error after upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46987856/path-must-be-a-string-received-undefined-after-upgrading-my-cordova-to-7-1-0), but I could not resolve them using these solutions. I am unsure why this may be happening because when I run `cordova build` it creates the apk without any issues.

I have tried removing the `node_modules` folder as well and running npm install in my `mobile` folder, but didn't help me.

I am unsure why this error is being caused and how to resolve it

result of `cordova requirements`:

```
Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: installed android-29,android-28,android-27
Gradle: installed /opt/gradle/gradle-5.2.1/bin/gradle
```

platform versions:

```
Installed platforms:
  android 8.1.0
Available platforms: 
  browser ^6.0.0
  electron ^1.0.0
  ios ^5.0.0
  osx ^5.0.0
  windows ^7.0.0
```

**package.json of my cordova project**:

```
{
  "name": "helloworld",
  "displayName": "HelloCordova",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "ecosystem:cordova"
  ],
  "author": "Apache Cordova Team",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "cordova-android": "^8.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.4"
  },
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resolved**: After digging in, I found out that Cordova was unable to launch the emulator, which is why I looked for a workaround and got it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36724018/cordova-not-finding-avd), which asked to manually start emulator using android studio and then run the build. Worked like a charm.